# cherrypicking commit on github, issues with some basic stuff

Tags: android, github

Im trying to cherrypick this commit before building a ROM from source: https://github.com/davidtrpcevski/android_frameworks_base/commit/4fcf26644f39db176440880ceafb41e56441d668

The commands i've used:
`cd frameworks/base
git fetch git@github.com:davidtrpcevski/android_frameworks_base.git ltefix && git cherry-pick 4fcf26644f39db176440880ceafb41e56441d668`

Here is the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFLJ4.jpg and `git status`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TaVV.jpg

Complete git newb there, any help is welcome.

Edit: I'm using Debian (Google Cloud) if that makes any difference.